# CLI arguments of create-nx-workspace

Tags: nrwl-nx

Is there some documentation regarding the arguments that `create-nx-workspace` takes? I'd like to build a *copy and paste*-able oneliner to set up a new workspace without any interactive questions asked. So far I have

```
npx create-nx-workspace@latest myworkspace --name myworkspace --preset web-components --appName myapp --cli angular
```

Next it's asking me which default stylesheet format I want to use. And I can't figure out how to specify that as a command line parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is not option to define style within create-nx-workspace command. As you can see there is only prompt to inquire style after determination of appName promise:

```
determineWorkspaceName(parsedArgs).then(name => {
    determinePreset(parsedArgs).then(preset => {
        return determineAppName(preset, parsedArgs).then(appName => {
            return determineStyle(preset).then(style => {
                return determineCli(preset, parsedArgs).then(cli => {
                    const tmpDir = createSandbox(packageManager, cli);
                    createApp(tmpDir, cli, parsedArgs, name, preset, appName, style);
                    showCliWarning(preset, parsedArgs);
                    showNxWarning(name);
                    pointToTutorial(preset);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Code of the determineStyle is [here](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/packages/create-nx-workspace/bin/create-nx-workspace.ts#L346).

I have already prepared PR to add this feature into create-nx-workspace command [here](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/pull/2294).

Comment: Wow, thanks! It's really cool that you even added a PR for this.

Comment: np. As a workaround you can use create-nx-workspace <name of workspace> --preset=empty and after that just add project e.g. angular using --style option which is already working

Comment: @kremerd PR is already merged into master so now you can wait for new release version to be able to use style option alongside your other options as well https://github.com/nrwl/nx/commit/77238e2ce770c6edd0b34a82dec1642a896598a8

Answer (score 2):

You may select the tools used for styling the application

```
npx create-nx-workspace@latest myworkspace ... --style=css
```

You may use on of the following options

- `css`, `scss`, `less` for Angular projects
- `styl` for all non-Angular, and
- `styled-components`, `@emotion/styled`, `styled-jsx` for React, Next.js and Gatsby.

---

### Command line options for NX

You can check the command line options that you can use to create the NX workspace by running

```
npx create-nx-workspace@latest --help
```

The following are the command line options for the `v13.4.5` version:

| Option | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `preset` | Tools to be used in the workspace (options: "apps", "empty", "core", "npm", "ts", "web-components", "angular", "angular-nest", "react", "react-express", "react-native", "next", "gatsby", "nest", "express") |
| `appName` | Name of the application |
| `cli` | CLI to be used (options: "nx", "angular") |
| `style` | style option (options: "css", "scss", "less" for Angular, "styl" for all non-Angular and "styled-components", "@emotion/styled", "styled-jsx" for React, Next.js and Gatsby) |
| `interactive` | enable interactive mode when using presets (boolean) |
| `packageManager` | package manager to use (npm, yarn, pnpm) |
| `nx-cloud` | yse Nx Cloud (boolean) |